# Disk of convergence of the series $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n!\,(z-i)^{n!} $

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n!(z-i)^{n!}
$$

Find the disk of convergence of this powerseries.

Can I set $n!=k$ and then deal with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty k z^k$ .

On another note $\frac{z^{(n+1)!}}{z^{n!}}$ converges when $|z|<1$.

Comment: Got something from an answer?

Comment: @Did Yes I did indeed , I also came across the statement that when $\sum_{n=o}^\infty \alpha_n z^{k(n)}$ then we have $ R^{-1}=lim_{n\to \infty}(\alpha_n)^{\frac{1}{k(n)}} $, which can also help in many cases , along with the understanding that $ \alpha_n z^{k(n)}\to 0$

Comment: This ad hoc criterion is a trivial consequence of the simpler and more general considerations in my answer. Cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One knows that $nw^n\to0$ if and only if $|w|\lt1$ hence $n!\,w^{n!}\to0$ if and only if $|w|\lt1$ (a small argument is necessary for the "and only if" direction but you should be able to find it) thus the disk of convergence is centered at $___$ with radius $____$.

---

Recall that the disk of convergence $D$ of a series $\sum\limits_na_nw^n$ is *characterized* by the following pair of properties:

- For every $w$ in the interior of $D$, $a_nw^n\to0$
- For every $w$ not in the closure of $D$, the sequence $(a_nw^n)$ is unbounded

*Exercise:* Replace the computational solutions of most MSE questions on the subject by a solution based on this "geometrical" characterization and watch the simplifications this shift of emphasis yields.

Comment: Intuitively I believe the center is $(0,i)$ and the radius 1, but how do I show it formally?

Comment: ?? Well, following my answer... which has nothing *intuitive* in the sense of not-fully-justified, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Almost. You need (a lot of) zero coefficients. Calling the function $f$, we have

$$f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\cdot z^k,$$

where

$$a_k = \begin{cases} k &, k = n!\\ 0 &, \bigl(\forall n\bigr)(k \neq n!).\end{cases}$$

Now the Cauchy-Hadamard formula gives you the radius of convergence easily.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Except for this approach what other way would you suggest?